# Include error (entity.inc) on multi site installation

Tags: multi-sites

I'm on a server where Drupal 7 was installed using the package manager. (Debian)

So the codebase is at `/usr/share/drupal7/` with the sites folder symlinking to `/etc/drupal/7/sites`

Let's assume the URL to our homepage is www.foo.com and we have two sites using the same codebase. So we have:

```
www.foo.com/site1
www.foo.com/site2

/etc/drupal/7/sites/foo.com.site1
/etc/drupal/7/sites/foo.com.site2
```

also at `/etc/drupal/7` we have a apache.conf doing:

```
Alias /site1 /usr/share/drupal7
Alias /site2 /usr/share/drupal7

<Directory /usr/share/drupal7/>
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```

It actually works nice. I can install sites and edit content and whatever. But now I wanted to copy a site from another server (Ubuntu - also package manager installation, so same "setup"). So I rsynced it and edited settings.php. [actually there's only the database info to update].
I then exported and imported the database and emptied all cache tables.

Let's say we copied the site to site1. If I go to www.foo.com/site1 I get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/usr/share/drupal7/sites/default/modules/entity/includes/entity.inc' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /usr/share/drupal7/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 3190
```

The code here is:

```
if ($file) {
  require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . $file;
  return TRUE;
}
else {
  return FALSE;
}
```

with `DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . $file` being `/usr/share/drupal7/includes/entity.inc`

DRUPAL_ROOT is set in index.php, which is located at /usr/share/drupal7/index.php. So I get the above strange file path.

Question 1: Why does the error say can't include `/usr/share/drupal7/sites/default/modules/entity/includes/entity.inc` although it actually should look for `/usr/share/drupal7/includes/entity.inc`? Does Drupal have some fallback mechanics here?

Question 2: How can I make the file paths correct? I think it shouldn't look for the file in /default but in /site1 or /site2 - according to which site I'm accessing.

Edit: the registry database is full of paths including /default - how can I rebuld it? (it was the default site on the old server)